# These two Bash lines are functionally equivalent. Can someone explain why one is faster?

Tags: bash, time, test

```
$ time if [[ $dir2 -ot $dir1 ]] ; then open $dir2 ; else open $dir1 ; fi
real    0m0.055s
user    0m0.023s
sys     0m0.018s

$ time  [[ $dir2 -ot $dir1 ]] && open $dir2 || open $dir1
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

At above, I compared two methods for testing which directory is older and then opening the older directory. I guess I'm just confused why the `&&` and `||` operators right after a test has the same functionality of an `if`/`then` test, and why it's faster. Are there advantages/disadvantages to each?

Comment: They are *not* functionally equivalent. In the second, if open dir2 fails, open dir1 will run. That cannot be the case in the first.

Comment: Related: [How can I time a pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364156)?

Answer (score 70):

`time` always times the directly following [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines).

> A *pipeline* is a sequence of one or more commands (simple or [compound](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Compound-Commands.html)) separated by one of the control operators `|` or `|&`.

`if ... fi` is a single compound command, and `[[ ... ]]` is one command. The part after `&&` is not measured by `time` because `foo && bar` is a [list of commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists-of-Commands).

Compare:

```
$ time if true; then sleep 1; fi

real    0m1.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s


$ time true && sleep 1

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

# example of pipeline separated with |:
$ time true | sleep 1

real    0m1.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

To measure time from all of the second commands, you can group them by putting it in (curly) brackets:

```
$ time { true && sleep 1; }

real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: Good catch! The `time` keyword only applies to the command (compound or simple) that it precedes. So to time properly in the second command, they would need to use `time open ... || time open ...`.

Comment: To be hideously exact, [Bash's `time` times a _pipeline_](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines), which can then contain simple or compound commands. `if-then-fi` is a compound command, which can be part of a pipeline, but `foo && bar` is a list of commands that can't be without being grouped in `{ }` or `( )`.

Comment: Try `command time ...` ;)

Comment: The `[ : ]` construct is completely different from just `:`. `:` is a command that simply exits with 0 (true) status (also called `true`). The `[` is another command that runs various tests, by default testing whether the argument is non-empty (which `:` is). If called with the name `[`, rather than the alternate name `test`, it requires an additional `]` argument.

Comment: @JanHudec, yes, though in practice they both return a truthy exit status, so it doesn't matter here. The time taken by both is also insignificant with the `sleep 1` right there next to them.

Comment: I used `[ : ]` instead of simply `true` because OP used the similar `[[ ... ]]` in the question.

Comment: @pLumo, 1. OP used `[[` consistently in both cases and 2. OP used it in the intended way while `[ : ]` basically works by accident.

Comment: @JanHudec, what do you mean "by accident"? `test` is defined to exit with a zero status (truthy) if only gets one argument that's not the empty string. (or one plus the tailing `]` in the case of `[`). Anyway, for the difference between `if` and `&&` it doesn't really matter how that truthy condition is acquired, so I edited this to use just `true` in every case. Perhaps that would be less distracting?

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes, the edit is good. What I mean with “by accident” is that the way it actually works is unlikely what author had in mind when they wrote it.