# A bash script does not go through all sleep commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

The code below is a simple bash script I am running on a Linux machine, and I was wondering that why the time interval between each output is **four** **seconds** instead of **eight**?

```
$ for test in test1 test2 test3; do (echo ${test}; sleep 4s; echo hop2; sleep 4s; echo hop3) | date;  done
Sun 11 Apr 2021 12:42:27 AM +07
Sun 11 Apr 2021 12:42:31 AM +07
Sun 11 Apr 2021 12:42:35 AM +07
```

Despite increasing the latter time value to be somewhat longer, the time interval between each output is still four seconds.

```
$ for test in test1 test2 test3; do (echo ${test}; sleep 4s; echo hop2; sleep 50s; echo hop3) | date;  done
Sun 11 Apr 2021 12:42:44 AM +07
Sun 11 Apr 2021 12:42:48 AM +07
Sun 11 Apr 2021 12:42:52 AM +07
```

This is very confusing, I will really appreciate it if anyone can explain this.

What'd more confusing is that if I put the `date` command in the front, it looks like none of the sleep commands are executed:

```
$ for test in test1 test2 test3; do (date; echo ${test}; sleep 50s; echo hop2; sleep 50s; echo hop3) | date;  done
Sun 11 Apr 2021 01:22:35 AM +07
Sun 11 Apr 2021 01:22:35 AM +07
Sun 11 Apr 2021 01:22:35 AM +07
```

Comment: You haven't defined hop2. Increase the first sleep by 50 seconds instead of the second sleep and see what happens.

Comment: @CinaedSimson I knew that if I changed the value of the first sleep, it will work as I expect, but why the second sleep doesn't do its job?

Comment: @answer this should help explain part of this: [How can I time a pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364157)

Comment: Date does not take input like that. Just replace the pipe with a semicolon inside the () might do what you expected? the echo hps dont make sense here either

Comment: See @GarfieldBonn comment. If I type "sleep 4s; echo hop2; sleep 4s; echo hop3; date" in a terminal window, it works. If I replace the last ";" with a "|" I get your problem.

Comment: "This is very confusing..." I agree. The entire script is on one long line. If you broke it down into separate statements it would be much easier to see what is happening.

Answer (score 16):

To clarify this, let me add add some debugging output to stderr (bypassing the pipe), before & after echoing "hop2":

```
$ for test in test1 test2 test3; do 
      (echo ${test}; sleep 4s; echo before hop2 >&2;
       echo hop2; echo after hop2 >&2; sleep 4s; echo hop3) | date;
  done
Sat Apr 10 11:29:46 PDT 2021
before hop2
Sat Apr 10 11:29:50 PDT 2021
before hop2
Sat Apr 10 11:29:54 PDT 2021
before hop2
```

Note that `echo after hop2 >&2` *never executes*, and neither do the commands after it: the second `sleep` and the `echo hop3`.

As I understand it, here's what happens. Within the loop, two separate processes execute in parallel, with output from the first piped to input of the second. The two processes execute:

```
echo ${test}
sleep 4s
echo before hop2 >&2
echo hop2
echo after hop2 >&2
sleep 4s
echo hop3
```

and

```
date
```

Here's the rough sequence of execution (the exact sequence of the first 3 steps and the beginning of step 4 will be somewhat random):

1. Process 1 executes `echo ${test}`; this writes "test1" (and a newline) into the pipe, where it's buffered so that it can be read later.
2. Process 2 executes `date`, printing the current date to the terminal.
3. Process 2 exits, closing its end of the pipe.
4. Process 1 executes `sleep 4s`.
5. After 4 seconds, process 1 executes `echo before hop2 >&2`, printing "before hop2" to the terminal.
6. Process 1 *tries* to execute `echo hop2`, but since the pipe's only reader has closed it, it gets a SIGPIPE errror. This apparently causes the entire subshell process (not just the `echo` command) to exit.

Note that this happens only because `echo` is a shell builtin; if you used `/bin/echo hop2` (an external command, instead of the shell's `echo` builtin) it would execute the second `sleep` as you expected.

BTW, this is relatively consistent between different shells. I get the same results running this in bash, zsh, dash, and ksh (interactively). ksh in a script is a bit different, because it apparently doesn't wait for process 1 to exit before continuing, so the `date`s all execute immediately, followed (4 seconds later) by a series of "before hop2" lines.

Comment: re. "the exact sequence of the first 3 steps", step 1 has to come before step 3, since otherwise the first echo would already trigger the signal. Good point on the builtin vs. external echo!

Answer (score 9):

```
(echo ${test}; ...) | date
```

What are you trying to do here? You're piping data to the stdin of `date`, but `date` doesn't read any input. It just prints the date and exits.

After `date` exits, the pipe closes, after which any data printed to it has nowhere to go and the process writing to the pipe, the subshell `(echo; sleep; echo; sleep)`, gets sent the SIGPIPE signal and it dies.

This is how pipelines work in general. If the left-hand side is something that can produce loads of output, perhaps even an arbitrary amount, the signal is what tells it to stop after the right-hand side loses interest.

E.g. in something like `cat /dev/zero | head -c128 > /dev/null`, the signal eventually kills the `cat` so it isn't left around indefinitely.
Neither the shell nor the `cat` prints an error message for that. It's just part of normal operation that pipes work like this. Similarly for the case at hand here. (In some cases you do get an error message though, just don't expect to always get one for this.)

(The outer loop doesn't affect the results, so I dropped it. You can use `time ( ... ) | ...` to measure the time the pipeline takes.)

In Bash, you can check the exit statuses of the commands in the pipeline from the `PIPESTATUS` array:

```
$ ( echo ${test}; sleep 4s; echo hop2; sleep 50s; echo hop3; ) |
    date;  declare -p PIPESTATUS
Sat Apr 10 21:34:56 EEST 2021
declare -a PIPESTATUS=([0]="141" [1]="0")
```

SIGPIPE is number 13 at least on Linux, so it matches the shown exit status 141 = 128 + signal number. (A process could also exit normally with status >= 128, but that's not the case here.)

Or, you could `strace` to see what happens:

```
$ strace -f bash -c '( echo ${test}; sleep 4s; echo hop2; 
                       sleep 50s; echo hop3; ) | date'
...
[pid 31647] write(1, "hop2\n", 5)       = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
[pid 31647] --- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=31647, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 31647] +++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
...
```

On the other hand, if there was something that reads the input on the right hand side of the pipe, there would be no SIGPIPE, and the whole pipeline would sleep for a total of 54 seconds:

```
$ time ( echo ${test}; sleep 4s; echo hop2; sleep 50s; echo hop3; ) |
       cat > /dev/null 

real    0m54.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Or, if you ignore the SIGPIPE on the writing side:

```
$ time ( trap '' PIPE; echo foo; sleep 4s; echo hop2; sleep 10s; 
         echo hop3; ) | date 
Sat Apr 10 21:57:07 EEST 2021
bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe
bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe

real    0m14.006s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

With SIGPIPE ignored, the shell gets a regular error return when writing to the closed pipe, and it does print an error for that.

---

Note that there's also a timing issue here between the left-hand side of the pipe writing to the pipe, and the right-hand side closing it.

If I do something like this:

```
( echo foo; echo bar; sleep 4s; ) | date;
```

the `sleep` does run. But if I replace the two `echo`'s with `for i in {1..100}; do echo foo; done;`, the LHS dies before getting to the `sleep`.
(The race here will depend on the system.)

And regarding the case with another `date` as the first thing on the LHS:

```
(date; echo ${test}; sleep 50s; echo hop2; sleep 50s; echo hop3) | date
```

This is also due to timing issues. Since `date` is an external command, it may well be slower for the shell to launch it, than to just internally handle an `echo` (it is a builtin in next to all shells, after all). That makes it more likely for the `date` on the right-hand side to win the race and close the pipe before the first `echo` gets to write to it.

---

In general, it's not very useful to write to pipes if your intent is not to pass some data to the other side, and if you have something else to do, make sure to handle the possible SIGPIPE.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing to send to `date` as it receives no data on stdin.

So, using a `|` is simply incorrect. I believe that you need to use `&&` instead.

But the question:

Why the time interval between each output is **four seconds** instead of **eight**?

Is still valid, but confusing to explain. The short answer is that the commands after `echo hop2` never get executed. The second sleep is never used.

```
$ (echo test; sleep 4s; echo hop2; sleep 4s; echo hop3) | date; date
Sun 11 Apr 2021 05:30:28 AM UTC
Sun 11 Apr 2021 05:30:32 AM UTC
```

If we use `stderr` instead of `stdout` all the commands execute:

```
$ (echo test >&2; sleep 4s; echo hop2 >&2; sleep 4s; echo hop3 >&2) | date; date

test
Sun 11 Apr 2021 05:32:36 AM UTC
hop2
hop3
Sun 11 Apr 2021 05:32:44 AM UTC
```

The reason is that `date` doesn't receive input in stdin, any attempt to write to it will be answered with a SIGPIPE and the whole (bash) shell (what is at the left of the `|`) will close. Breaking any other command in the list.

The reason for the very first `echo` on your example to succeed is time dependent:

1. At the beginning, the running shell will set up the pipe `|`.
2. To do that, it opens a child where the command `date` is started.
3. Without waiting for anything, the shell returns to the other side of the pipe and (in another child) asks it to execute `echo ${test}`.
4. Since the pipe is still open (`date` haven't closed it) the output of the echo is buffered and the command `sleep 4s` gets executed.
5. The `date` command gets enough time to end and close the pipe.
6. Now, with the pipe closed the next `echo` will not be able to write to it. It will cause a SIGPIPE.
7. On receiving a SIGPIPE the child shell on the left side of the `|` exits completely (the echo is a builtin and errors on built-ins cause the failure of the whole shell).
8. No more commands on the pipe will be executed.

That is why this:

```
$ (sleep 1; echo test; sleep 4s; echo hop2 >&2; ) | date ; date 

Sun 11 Apr 2021 06:10:04 AM UTC
Sun 11 Apr 2021 06:10:05 AM UTC
```

Doesn't even print the first echo. The time could be as small as 0.1 seconds. That is enough to allow `date` to end.

It even could be a call to an external command that delay the `echo` just enough:

```
(/usr/bin/true; echo test; sleep 4s; echo confirm >&2 ) | date; date
Sun 11 Apr 2021 06:27:01 AM UTC
Sun 11 Apr 2021 06:27:01 AM UTC
```

Your `for` loop is just the above repeated three times. Thus only four seconds between each loop.