# why is "read" through each line of a file much faster than "xargs"

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I have a large input file which contains 30M lines, new lines in `\r\n`. I decided to do something silly and compare the speed of counting all lines via `read -r` compared to `xargs` (stripping the `\r` first, because `xargs` does not seem to be able to split on multiple characters). Here are my two commands:

```
time tr -d '\r' < input.txt | xargs -P 1 -d '\n' -I {} echo "{}" | wc -l
```

```
time while read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]; do echo "$p"; done < input.txt | wc -l
```

Here, the second solution is **much** faster. Why is that?

Please note that I know that this is not a proper way to count lines of a file. This question is merely out of interest of my observation.

Comment: I just realized that this might have something to do with `xargs` spawning a `/usr/bin/echo` process for each line, while the second command is probably using the bash `echo` directive, instead of a process. I'll check that.

Comment: You also have the overhead of the `tr`. And how are you measuring the time here? [Timing a pipe is complicated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364156/22222).

Comment: I would have expected that the overhead of `tr` should be minimal. Regarding timing, I just write `time` in front of both commands, so including the overhead of `tr` indeed.

Comment: Well, you're launching `tr`, `xargs` and `/bin/echo` on each invocation while the shell one doesn't call any external tools at all. That will likely explain it, but I'm not sure. Can you also show the actual results you get? It's hard to understand what "much faster" means without them.

Comment: Right, will do. I am now executing a test when I used `/usr/bin/echo` for the `read` and it does also seem to take ages now. I will added these measurements later on.

Comment: The `tr` in the first version is not doing anything -- it is waiting for input from the terminal. The `xargs` is reading from the redirection `<`, not the pipe `|`.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I fixed that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, as you suspected, `xargs -P 1 -d '\n' -I {} echo "{}"`, which is actually the same as `xargs -rd '\n' -n1` as `echo` is the default command, will fork a process and execute the standalone `echo` in the child process while waiting for its termination in the parent for each line of input.

So that's a lot more work than even using the inefficient `read` builtin and the `echo` builtin all in the same shell process.

If instead of GNU `xargs`, you use busybox `xargs` which (at least in some configurations and recent versions) will call the busybox `echo` internally without forking a process, you'll notice it will be significantly faster than the `bash` loop.

For a more relevant comparison, you should compare:

```
tr -d '\r' | xargs -rd'\n' -n1
```

with

```
tr -d '\r' |
  while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
   /bin/echo "$line"
  done
```

Which are likely to give you similar outcomes as the bulk of the time will be spent forking processes and executing  the standalone `echo`.

Here, on the output of `seq 3e7` and measuring with `pv -al > /dev/null` (to measure throughput in `a`verage number of `l`ines per second), I get around:

- 1.12M/s for busybox xargs
- 70k/s for bash loop with builtin echo
- 860/s for GNU xargs
- 850/s for bash loop with /bin/echo

Comment: Thank you Stéphane, It was indeed the overhead of spwaning the `echo` process for each line which was resulting the performance drop. I learned some interesting stuff in your answer (`pv -al` to measure performance, busybox `xargs` <-> GNU `xargs`, ...) as well!