# How to store inner output of a nested bash command (within parenthesis) into one file and outer output into another file?

Tags: bash, time

Here's my command:

```bsh
(time ( \
   time sleep 1; \
   time sleep 2 \
) 2>&1 | tee inner.txt ) 2>&1 | tee outer.txt
```

`cat inner.txt` shows:

```
real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s

real    0m2.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s
```

and `cat outer.txt` shows:

```
real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s

real    0m2.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s

real    0m3.068s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.008s
```

How can I get just this into `outer.txt`?:

```
real    0m3.068s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Even better, how can I get `inner.txt`, `outer.txt`, and `both.txt`, where `both.txt` would contain:

```
real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s

real    0m2.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s

real    0m3.068s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Note that the `time` cmd I'm using above is the bash built-in function `time`, *not* the `/usr/bin/time` command, which I learned about through my question here: [How to pass optional arguments to `time` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/699799/114401)

I'm on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

This question is a follow-up to my answer here, in order to try to improve that answer: [How to time a multiline, multi-subcommand command in bash, and optionally store all output into a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/699728/114401)

Comment: `tee` prints to a file and `stdout` - use output redirection instead in the inner part if you don't want the inner output in `outer.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

For one, I think your inner `tee` is feeding the outer, i.e. when that `tee` prints to its stdout, it's redirected to the outer pipe along with anything else that's output on the outer level. In addition, on my Bash, I had to change the inner parentheses to braces to make it work (I've no idea why).

This seemed to work to get the output to the files (only):

```
(time { 
         time sleep 1;
         time sleep 2;
      } > inner.txt 2>&1
) > outer.txt 2>&1
```

To get the output to both the files and the terminal / the script's stdout, you'll need to arrange the inner `tee` to output "around" the outer one. E.g. save the script's stdout to another free file descriptor and print to that:

```
exec 3>&1;

(time {
         time sleep 1;
         time sleep 2;
      } 2>&1 | tee inner.txt >&3
) 2>&1 | tee outer.txt >&3
```

(The `>&3` isn't necessary on the outer one, I just did it for symmetry. You could also print directly to the terminal with `tee ... >/dev/tty` (no need for the `exec`), but then redirecting or piping the output of the whole script won't work.)

With the above, you could do `myscript |tee both.txt` to get the three output files.